# Is soft word wrap possible in Eclipse with the Scala plugin?

Tags: eclipse, scala, word-wrap

I'd like soft word wrap in the [Eclipse Scala IDE](http://www.scala-ide.org/) (soft == no change to the underlying file, just a change to the view of the file). Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. There's an [open bug report from 2003](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779) to add this for Eclipse's editors, but I guess it's unlikely that we're going to see this implemented soon. The bug report also [mentions a plug-in](http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/), but I haven't used it.